# ASP.Net Core Windows Auth - Cache Claims in Cookies

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, windows-authentication, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I'm porting a web application from ASP.Net to ASP.Net Core and need to support both Windows Integrated Authentication and Cookie Authentication with users stored in the apps database (the app is self-hosted by customers and different customers use different authentication methods and sometime migrate from one to the other).

In order to share as much code as possible between the authentication methods I'm using a ClaimsTranformer to add claims to the Windows Auth Users that match those that Cookie Auth (using ASP.Net Core Identity) gives me. However, I would like these claims to be stored in a cookie (in a secure way, like Identity does for the cookie auth) so that I don't have to be hitting the database on every request. Is there a way to do this?

In ASP.Net, I used to look up the user details for the Windows user on the first request and then SignIn with ASP.Net Identity cookie auth; The app would then just use cookie auth the same as if the user had been authenticated with user/password. Unfortunately in Core, it seems that as soon as I call services.AddIdentity in Startup.ConfigureServices, it disables Windows Integrated Authentication.

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2.1 on .Net Framework 4.7 (although we have plans to migrate to .Net Core in a future version, when we can remove some dependencies).

Comment: Did you solved this? Maybe just use in memory cache...

Comment: I've not found a good solution as yet. I'm still relying on ClaimsTransformer running on each request. Server side caching is problematic as this raises the issue of when to free up the cache. The server normally doesn't have any knowledge of the active sessions, everything is kept client side.